# How do I add a note to the work item history programmatically in TFS?

Tags: version-control, tfs

In Visual Studio TFS work items have History tab you can add your comments to. Build agent can also contribute to the discussion, which is nice. I would like for more tools to leave their opinion in this History.

How do I programmatically add a note to the work item history like svcTFSBuid does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the TFS API to add a new entry in the history. The [WorkItem.History](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitem.history(v=vs.120).aspx) property will do the work:

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem testCase = new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem(workItemTypes["Test Case"]);
testCase.History = "created by TFS";
ArrayList workItemErrors = testCase.Validate();
if (testCase.IsValid())
{
       testCase.Save();
 }
```

Comment: This code seems to work on a new created WorkItem. When i execute a query and try this code on an existing WorkItem, i get an exception that says: You have tried to set a value on a field that is only partially opened. If i  loop through all the revisions and  read the field named "History" prior to setting a value to the History property, then it works. Does anyone have a clue why this is so?